# Debugging the Abort crash with native crashlog on Android

Tags: xamarin, crash, visual-studio-debugging, android-10.0, abort

In the play-store,
I am seeing one particular crash, which is being faced by a lot of users.

Crash-log has the following detail:

Title : “abort”
Detail:
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.x.y <<< backtrace:

## 00 pc 0000000000081f74 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)

## 01 pc 0000000000245ab0 /data/app/com.x.y-aYjDsZRe6QZhuGCy8Cef8A==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so

Crash is happening on the following android version:
Android 8.1, 9, 10 only.

For the lower versions,
It appears as “tgkill” in lower versions as per my understanding.

I am not able to reproduce such crash in my internal debugging/testing and this does not get caught by the crash-reporting tool either.
But this crash and its affected users constitute the significant %age of overall crashes reported on play-store.

In the crash-log, I noticed that pid and tid both are 0.
I am guessing that it might be that App is getting stuck (like an ANR) and OS is killing the application without giving option to user to wait.

Update:
90+% of the Crashes are coming from Android 10 only.

I searched a little and found that many other are facing this issue as well, but there is no one generic fix as i understand.

I am not able to reproduce the issue locally so far, so don't have a clue on what might be wrong.
Does anyone has any pointers on where to add more logs to get more details about the problem?

Comment: Can you please run the below command and share the result```adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S```

Comment: Thanks @AnupamChaplot for responding.
Here is what you asked to try:
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S 
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main

As i mentioned, i am not able to see or reproduce the crash on my device or emulator.